# How to use key down event with Html text box helper in MVC4

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.5, onkeydown

How do you add a key down event with this text box?

```
@Html.TextBox("txtbx1", "", new {...} )
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Or would you rather not use a library and do straight JavaScript?

Comment: I ended up using jquery

Comment: Adding solution: $('#id').on('keydown', function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
               //do something
            }
        });

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtbx1", "", new { onkeydown="MyFunction();" } )
```

Comment: How can i access event parameters in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.

Call:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BoardSizeX, new { @onkeydown = "return Foo(event, $(this).val());"})
```

Function:

```html
 function foo(event, currentValue) {
       console.log(event);
       console.log(currentValue);

       return true; 
}
```